# Secure Linux Server Setup To Run Scripts via PHP exec()?

Tags: php, security, server, phantomjs

I'd like to run a script (phantomJS) via php `exec()` or `shell_exec()`. Everything is working fine on my development system.

I've installed phantomJS on my production server, and have run it successfully from the terminal after logging in via SSH.

But when I run it from PHP via `exec()` or `shell_exec()`, I get messages saying:

> `GLIBCXX_3.xx` not found
>
> `GLIBC_2.xx` not found

The support team at the web hosting provider is saying they don't know how to enable the server to access the script and still maintain security:

> We're not familiar with the specifics of it, so we'll either have to
> go through with disabling the chroot, but as our supervisor mentioned
> this will allow all accounts on the server to account with each other
> which is what the chroot prevents.
>
> You can have your own system administrators look at the setup as you
> do have root access, and see if they can devise a workaround, but on
> our end this is the only thing we can suggest.

They are running CentOS, which is a 64-bit Linux OS.

I have very good experience with this web host up to this time, so I'm hoping there's a way to address this without changing hosts.

I have full root access to the account, so I can configure it in any way necessary.

Can anyone make some suggestions about how I might configure my production server to access phantomJS while maintaining a secure server?

**UPDATE**

Apparently my app is in a "chrooted environment" without full root access to GLIB on the server.  The web host is saying there will be a lack of security if my php user is given full root access.

Comment: Does the user which the webserver uses to execute php (if apache or nginx default would be www-data) have permission to run the command for phantomJS?

Comment: I will check with the web host to confirm.

Comment: It seems that PhantonJS has broken dependencies. Here is a similar issue, perhaps PhantomJS does not support your CentOS version: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13940

Comment: @manoelhc, I was able to successfully run phantomJS from the terminal after logging in to my production server via SSH, so it appears that phantomJS does run as expected on the host's CentOS version.

Comment: Are you able to run any other command? Maybe PHP is resetting an LD_LIBRARY_PATH-like envvar, and PhantomJS is not able to find those libs.

Comment: @commanderZiltoid, yes, the same user running php is also the one with access to phantomJS. I'm learning more and will update the main post with additional info.

Comment: @VikR I think you might change your architecture approach by adding a newly separated service to trigger PhantomJs from PHP script via API or MQ.

Comment: @manoelhc Thanks for this great suggestion! Would that service have to live on another server so as to be able to access GLIB?

Comment: @VikR I can be on the same server, but not under your current web server. I don't know which type of access and permission you have (SSH, FTP, etc.). If you're able to access the terminal, you can do something like this:
Create your API in PHP to exec() your PhantomJS command and run it on terminal: `php -S localhost:8000`. In your main Web App, you call this API to trigger PhantomJS. This is a super simple solution, and you can improve it a lot.

Comment: Thanks @manoelhc. I will look into it.

Comment: @manoelhc I wound up following your suggestion. If you'd like to post it as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove your PhantomJS system call and create an API layer or a service that subscribes an MQ queue and then integrate it with PHP to avoid several problems, including the chroot limitation.